# Is there a way to stop Xcode from switching to split view when running?

Tags: xcode, ide

I'm recording some video tutorials and would really like to disable the split view that Xcode automatically switches to when you build and run. Below is an example of what I'm talking about.

**Before clicking build:**

[image]

**After build clicked:**

[image]

### Question

Is there a way to stop Xcode from switching to split view when running the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, it can easily be disabled in the behaviors menu.

[image]